# Display custom name for breadcrumb items - Angular5

Tags: angular

i have installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng5-breadcrumb package for displaying breadcrumbs.

The code changes are  as follows.

app.module.ts

```
import {Ng5BreadcrumbModule, BreadcrumbService} from 'ng5-breadcrumb

 imports: [
...
    Ng5BreadcrumbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
...
    BreadcrumbService
  ],
```

account-list.component.ts

```
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'ng5-breadcrumb';

providers: [UtilsService, DialogService, BreadcrumbService]

  constructor(
    private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService
    ) {

    breadcrumbService.addFriendlyNameForRoute('/accounts', 'My accounts');
  }
```

The above code displays the breadcrumb on the page. But the addFriendlyNameForRoute method is not working. I need the breadcrumb to be displayed as 'My Accounts'.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you find a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your app.component.html(your main component) just before router outlet like:

```
<breadcrumb ></breadcrumb>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```